# Linux centos 6,64 - How do I make wget to save the files in an ordered numeric specific format?

Tags: linux

would like wget to give as result files named in order file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt and so on instead of being saved with their original names, while using linux centos 6,64. Which command would need to add for this? Thanks

Comment: If you want to get more help, please [edit] your question to describe how you know what URLs to fetch and exactly what happened when you tried [Nasir Riley’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1285531/354511#1285537).   (Do not respond in comments.)

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

```
wget -O file1.txt http://website/filename.txt
```

Comment: Hello Nasir, thanks for your reply. I am trying to mirror download a website (has many links). Then actually what I need is that each link comes organized in file1.txt then file2.txt and so on only growing the numbers. The suggestion you sent makes the full download be saved inside file1.txt only. Is there a way that each link comes separated just changing names organizedly autogenerating the number after word "file" until it ends the full download? Thanks

Comment: My code shows you how to save a file to a different filename which is what you asked. If you want each download to be saved in increasing increments, then you'll need to use a for loop. I've edited my answer to give you a basis for how to do so. You'll have to modify it for your needs.

Comment: Hello Nasir, when using wget -O does the file1.txt has a limit size while using linux or cmd or only the server memory is the limit? thank you

Comment: There is no limit on the file size. If you want a very simple way to do it then you can just write a script where you use the first code in my answer and just plug in the desired file names and links instead of having to modify a for loop. It wouldn't be as dynamic but it would do exactly what you want.

Comment: I took out the for loop as it doesn't work properly upon testing.

Comment: Hello Nasir, ok, thanks. One last question, in this wget -O, if I add the -c it will continue writing to the file1.txt if I restart from where it stopped same as in the normal mode?

Comment: The -c switch is not necessary if the connection is lost or stopped with wget. That option is only necessary if the download was started prior to using wget. If you just want to start the download again then wget-O *samenewfilename.txt* *http://samelink/sameoldfilename.txt will do the trick.